# Download all installed packages

Tags: linux, package-management, distributions

I need to download all installed packages of my current distribution. I am going to need only packages that either were updated or installed **after** fresh installation. (I prefer not to download packages that were installed by default)

#### Motivation

I am trying to make a repository of my currently installed packages, and move that repository to another computer which is located in somewhere with unstable radio link (so I can't download the packages). And I know how to make a repository using `reprepro` and I know how to download packages without installing them. Howewer the problem is to find which packages have been installed or updated.

Distribution: Kubuntu 17.10

Package Manager: apt, dpkg

Comment: It looks like an XY Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you need to do?

Comment: @dr01 Good point. Updated the question.

Comment: I think this answers your question https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages

Comment: Here's my answer to a similar question but for RHEL, you can get some hint from there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/443151/34039

Comment: @Arushix That actually lists packages that were installed manually, but not those whom were updated after installation.

Comment: `ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/ | grep list > last-packages-installed.txt` : Will save a text file with installed packages with the install date / in date order → It should be possible to see what's installed / updated after OS install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kubuntu uses `apt`:

`apt list --installed` will get you a list of installed packages.

`apt-get -d install <packages>` will download, but not unpack or install, packages (presumably into something under `/var/cache/`), though you know that already.

Your best bet, I would suggest, would be to string these together in a script, maybe with a bit of `sed` magic as necessary.

Comment: Doesn't `apt list --installed` also list  packages that were installed by default on OS installation?

Comment: Well sure, but there's no real way to avoid that -- moreover, specifically in your situation, it's difficult to be sure that the machine with a dodgy network connection will actually have the same packages, due to the possibility of different choices being made on install, and such.

That said, what you could do is run `apt list --installed` on the target machine, get the list back to the connected machine, and exploit The Power Of `diff` to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called  [`apt-clone`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/apt-clone) which can be used to clone/restore the packages on a apt based system. It will save/restore the packages, `sources.list`, keyring and automatic-installed states. It can also save/restore no longer downloadable packages using `dpkg-repack`.